# What is the name of the song Alex sings?

Tags: music, gangsta

In the anime Gangsta, while in Bastard, Alex recognizes a song she knows from her childhood. Later in the anime, by the end of episode 8, she sings that song to entertain the guests in Bastard. What is the name of that song?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/25183/Gangsta.), the track is called `With You (featuring Alex Bendetto)` by `Mamiko Noto`.

Comment: Note that Mamiko Noto is Alex's voice actor.